# zsh環境によるanacondaコンソール起動に失敗する

Tags: macos, anaconda, zsh

シェルをbashからzshに変更したのですがanacondaのコンソールが使えなくなりました。
コンソールを起動すると

```
❯ /Users/username/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool ; exit;
/Users/username/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Users/username/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool: line 1: `bash --init-file <(echo "source activate /Users/username/opt/anaconda3;")'

[プロセスが完了しました]
```

と出力されます。

**試したこと**
https://ts-engine.net/wp/archives/1068に従い、パスを通しました。
condaコマンドは使えるようになりましたが依然として出力は変わりません。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 英語版 Stack Overflow での類似質問です: [Anaconda not found in ZSh?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40370467/5989200)　手元に環境が無いので試せませんが、もし Bash を使っていた際に `conda init` をしていたのなら `conda init zsh` で直せそうだなと思っています。（もしこれで直ったら、[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)して頂けると嬉しいです）

Comment: superuser での類似質問 [Anaconda not working in Mac Catalina](https://superuser.com/q/1456518/680903) と、それを元にした Qiita の記事 [macOS Catalina にしたら、Anaconda 使えなくなった場合の対処法](https://qiita.com/akinko/items/1909c8d0145d9ba530b9) がありました。

Comment: ありがとうございました。解決しました。回答で示していただいたサイトを参考に`conda init zsh`  `conda update conda`　 `conda update jupyter`でうまく行きました。

Comment: 良かったです。是非解決法を（コメントでなくて）回答として投稿していただけると嬉しいです。もしかしたら上のコメントを投稿された際は時間制限のせいでできなかったかもしれませんが、今ならできるようになっていると思います。しばらく経つと自分の回答を承認することもできるようになります :)

Answer (score 1):

ありがとうございました。解決しました。

コメント欄で示していただいたサイトを参考にして、以下の通り実行するとうまく行きました。

```
conda init zsh
conda update conda
conda update jupyter
```